# How do I set up azure dev ops for a 2d unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, devops

I'm not sure if this is possible, I couldn't find any resources for building a 2d unity project (though there is for a 3d). 
The project I am currently working on is in a github repo and I would like to put it on dev ops. Every time a commit is made I would like to build and run unit and integration tests so that my team will know if something is not working correctly instead of manually doing it. It would also be nice to put inno installer in the build process (to make sure the installer would work without any problems, I don't know if that is possible on dev ops though).

On the 3d project (link: https://dinomite-studios.github.io/unity-azure-pipelines-tasks/), I don't know if it would work for a 2d project.

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question! If there is any clarification that I can make please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should *try* if it works with 2d, and get back to this question if it doesn't work normally.